# Include dependancies to package.json in NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm new to node.js I've been adding libraries to node_modules manually, without using the command line NPM install ... Now, I'm ending up with many libraries that are not included in the package.json.
Is there anyway to automatically add the dependancies from my node_modules to my package.json file ?

Comment: Try `npm init` this will ask you a bunch of questions, and then write a package.json for you, form now onwards please use `npm install --save` to save it to **package.json**